# Alternative definition of equivalent Cauchy sequences in a metric space

Tags: metric-spaces, equivalence-relations, cauchy-sequences, complete-spaces

Suppose $M$ is a metric space, not necesserily complete.

Given the following definition of Cauchy sequence:

> For every $\epsilon > 0$ there exists an open $\epsilon$-ball that contains all but a finite number of elements of the sequence.

consider the following equivalence relation:

> **def1.** Cauchy sequences $\{a_i\}$ and $\{b_i\}$ are equivalent iff $\{a_0, b_0, a_1, b_1, a_2, b_2, \ldots\}$ is a Cauchy sequence.

I came up with a following alternative definition of the equivalence:

> **def2.** $\{a_i\}$ and $\{b_i\}$ are equivalent iff for every $\epsilon > 0$ there exists
> an open $\epsilon$-ball that contains an infinite number of both $\{a_i\}$ and $\{b_i\}$.

**Question**: So, are **def1** and **def2** indeed equivalent?

It seems to me that they are not, but I can neither prove it nor think of a counterexample.
Intuitively, **def2** fails to address that there's a finite number of elements of $\{a_0, b_0, a_1, b_1, \ldots\}$ outside the ball.
This observation helped me to came up with a counterexample to a similar statement:

> $\{a_i\}$ and $\{b_i\}$ are equivalent iff (some ball
> contains infinite number of elements of $\{a_i\}$) always implies (this same ball contains an infinite number of elements of $\{b_i\}$).

The counterexample: $M = \mathbb{R}$, $a_i = (-\frac{1}{2})^i$, $b_i = -\frac{1}{2^i}$, and the ball $B_\epsilon$ could be taken to be $(0, 2\epsilon)$.

An example with multiple limit points could be a problem. However, it is easy to prove that a Cauchy sequence can have no more than 1 limit point, and both **def1** and **def2** require $\{a_i\}$ and $\{b_i\}$ to be Cauchy sequences.

Answer (score 0):

I think that rather than "some ball contains an infinite number of elements of both ${a_i}$ and ${b_i}$," you want "some ball contains all but a finite number of ${a_i}$ and ${b_i}$. Notice that "containing an infinite number" is a weaker condition than "containing all but a finite number". In the reals, an $\epsilon$-ball around $1$ contains infinitely many elements of the sequence $(-1)^n$, but it certainly does not contain all but finitely many terms.

Comment: That's true. But can we drop this "but a finite" addendum, could the weaker requirement be equivalent? Note that both sequences to be considered equivalent are Cauchy, so they can't have multiple limit points as $(-1)^n$ does.

Comment: Ah, I see. Ok, to show equivalence, you need to show def1 $\iff$ def2. Hopefully def1$\implies$ def2 is clear. For the other direction, see if you can show the following lemma: Let ${a_i}$ be Cauchy, and let $B$ be a ball that contains infinitely many terms of ${a_i}$. Then if fact $B$ contains all but finitely many terms of ${a_i}$.

Comment: Unfortunately, this lemma would be a false claim. I gave a counterexample in the post: consider $a_i = (-\frac{1}{2})^i$ and $(0,2\epsilon)$ as a ball. Then the ball contains an infinite number of elements, but there is also an infinite number of elements outside of it.

Comment: Ack, you're right! I'm sorry, I'm off my game today. I'll keep thinking about it.